# Passing arguments to event handlers and getting the value in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have implemented pagination component which has 5 pages in total. Pagination is child component of `home component`.

When I click on page 1 it should get page number through `getpagenumber()` and `handleClick()` which makes use of page number but in below code `getpagenumber()` does not work when we click on page number.

pagination.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Pagination extends Component {

    getpagenumber(val){
        return val;
    }

    handleClick(){
    this.setState({
        end:getpagenumber()*16,
        start:end-16
    });
    const end = getpagenumber()*16;
    this.props.onChange(end - 16, end);
    }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Content/>
          <div className="container">                 
              <ul className="pagination">
                <li {this.getpagenumber(1)} onClick={this.handleClick}><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li {this.getpagenumber(2)} onClick={this.handleClick}><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li {this.getpagenumber(3)} onClick={this.handleClick}><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li {this.getpagenumber(4)} onClick={this.handleClick}><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li {this.getpagenumber(5)} onClick={this.handleClick}><a href="#">5</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Pagination;
```

home.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Pagination from './pagination';
import Content from './content';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        start:0,
        end:16
        };
    }

    onChangePagination = (start, end) => {
        this.setState({
          start:start,
          end:end
        });
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Content start={start} end={end}/>
          <Pagination onChange={this.onChangePagination}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exaggerating a bit. All you need is this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Pagination extends Component {
    handleClick(value){
      this.setState({
          end: value*16,
          start: end-16
      });
      const end = value*16;
      this.props.onChange(end - 16, end);
    }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Content/>
          <div className="container">                 
              <ul className="pagination">
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 1)}>1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 2)}>2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 3)}>3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 4)}>4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 5)}>5</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Pagination;
```

Notes:

- Maybe consider even passing the number of pages to the Pagination component and then generating an array from 1 to that number and just mapping out the li with the clicks.
- Clicks should go on the link tags.

Comment: Nice answer so you have removed `getpagenumber()` and instead of that you have passed value directly to `handleClick` am I right ?

Comment: @stonerock Yes. that's the way you bind arguments to a function

Comment: If Want to use filter like display items per page 5,10,15.. then above code will not able to do it so should I go with react-router if I want to display items with filter also if we increase items per page then number of pages should decrease and vice-versa.

Comment: @stonerock you can easily use react-router in combination with the componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method. But you can do it without react-router too. It's up to you basically

Comment: Thanks I will try it out :)